# Set up an apache reverse proxy with SSL certs and multiple domains

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I need help configuring Apache to act as a reverse proxy with https and multiple domains, such that `www.myfirstdomain.com` and `www.myseconddomain.com` both point to `x.x.x.x` and than the server will selectively forward to, let's say, `x.x.x.x:2400` (`myfirstdomain.com`, http), `x.x.x.x:2401` (`myfirstdomain.com`, https), `x.x.x.x`:2600 (`myseconddomain.com`, http) and `x.x.x.x:2601` (`mysecondomain.com`, https).

I tried many options but in the end I got stuck because I issued more than 5 certs (renews) per week and also I couldn't make it work.

`myfirstdomain.com` and `www.myfirstdomain.com` (http and https) were configured as follows:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2400/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2400/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2401/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2401/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2400>
    ServerName myfirstdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.myfirstdomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myfirstdomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myfirstdomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2401>
    ServerName myfirstdomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myfirstdomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I generated the certs with `certbot --apache` for both www and non-www and I had this file:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2401/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2401/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:2401>
        ServerName myfirstdomain.com
        ServerAlias www.myfirstdomain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        # Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
        # because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

        #     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myfirstdomain.com
        #     RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

        #     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myfirstdomain.com
        #     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]


        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myfirstdomain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myfirstdomain.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to regenerate the HTTPS certificates but it won't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that Apache listens on a range of ports, for instance 80 and 443.

**Virtualhosts** use the same ports (80 and 443) and Apache selects the correct folder using the domain name you use.

For example, **myfirstdomain.com** could display /var/www/html/myfirstdomain/public, but
if apache listens on port 80, it never match the rule for *:2400.

I haven't tryed this, but you could put ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in each virtual hosts and leave the port to :80 or :443.

When you call **myfirstdomain.com:80**, the rule on apache match and it executing proxing to another server.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/510767/407188).

LetsEncrypt create an ACME challenge (a file with a random string) that could be reachable from the internet. The Certification Server search this file, if exists the certificate is released; if not, it throw an error.

I don't remember the correct pathof the file,  but you must verify:

- can you reach "myfistdomain.com" from the internet?
- an external server can reach "myfistdomain.com" ? (check dns name and port forwarding of your router
- can you open the ACME challenge file?
- can the server open the ACME challenge file?

On some Plesk installations acme files cannot be reacheable because Plesk adds some automatic rules.